# Why is MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS not working with folder.createFile?

Tags: file-io, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, mime-types, google-docs

I am making a google script with some very basic functionality. There are errors however, that I do not understand.
The code below works. The HTML sample is from the documentation at

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(String,String)

```
function make50 () {
  var folder = DocsList.createFolder("NewLogFolder3");
  folder.createFile('New HTML File', '<b>Hello, world!</b>', MimeType.HTML);

  DriveApp.createFile("file", '', MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
}
```

Since the above works and the documentation for folder.createFile is the same as for driveApp.createFile,

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(String,String,String)

Why can't I do the following?

```
folder.createFile('new file', '', MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
```

When I try to do this, I get

> Invalid mime type. (line 42, file "Code")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **DocumentApp**.create('file name') to create a Google Doc.

You can't change the MimeType to a Google Doc through **DriveApp**.createFile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I understand it is that I mixed old and new code.

The DocsList class that I was using to create the folder is something I got from old StackOverflow posts.

Using DriveApp instead of DocsList, it works as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var docs = DocumentApp.create('My new file');

DriveApp.getFileById(docs.getId()).moveTo(folder);
```

```
createFile(name, content, mimeType)
```

Works with `MimeType.HTML` or `MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_TEXT` but not with `MineType.GOOGLE_DOCS`... who know... a bit useless :D

Answer (score -1):

Odd thing is this used to work. I just came back to try a script I know worked in the past. It now throws an invalid mime type error... odd thing is it does work with the kix file type

```
folder.createFile(filename, "", 'application/vnd.google-apps.document');
```

Comment: If you have a related problem, please consider Asking a new question. Answer posts shall propose a solution to the O.P.

Comment: Indeed apologies my bad